# Clean up class files after build with ant

Tags: java, ant

So I am using ant and I have it compiling and running properly but I want to have it delete all of the .class files after it is finished with the output. I thought I was doing it the right way but apparently I am not.

Here's my code:

```
<project default="run">
   <description>
      Compile/run all the files
   </description>

   <presetdef name="javac">
      <javac includeantruntime="false" />
   </presetdef>

   <target name="prob1" depends='compile'>
      <java classname='prob1'>
         <classpath path='./' />
         <arg value='Gertrude' />
      </java>
   </target>

   <target name="prob2" depends='compile'>
      <java classname='prob2'>
         <classpath path='./' />
         <arg value='28' />
      </java>
   </target>

   <target name="prob3" depends='compile'>
      <java classname='prob3'>
         <classpath path='./' />
         <arg value='2001' />
      </java>
   </target>

   <target name="prob4" depends='compile'>
      <java classname='prob4'>
         <classpath path='./' />
         <arg value='3' />
     </java>
   </target>

   <target name="compile">
      <javac srcdir='./' />
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete>
         <fileset dir="." includes="*.class"/>
      </delete>
   </target>
</project>
```

Comment: why do you want to clean up the class files?

Comment: @smcg It is for an assignment and my instructor likely wants me to clean up the files after I run it. He has an example but it didn't work for me so that's why I ask.

Comment: I would discourage from always cleaning up the class files automatically, because you would have to build every time you want to run the program. instead, just run `ant clean` to clean the files when you need to.